# Nimbus Look and feel returns Null for UIManager.getColor("inactiveCaptionBorder")

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I am getting NPE here:

```
Color base = UIManager.getColor("inactiveCaptionBorder");
```

while

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
```

is set to the application.

Any information is appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value for `inactiveCaptionBorder` doesn't exist in the [Nimbus Defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary), looks like as this value from [SystemColor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SystemColor.html) isn't directly applied in [Nimbus Look and Fee](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)l (I searching for String with value inactive in the Nimbus defaults and foud there only two values == `inactiveCaption`, `textInactiveText`)

list of [UIDefaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) by @camickr

Comment: Thanks mKorbel. But I don't understand `(inactive == inactiveCaption, textInactiveText)`.

Comment: :-) looks like as I'm in critical and safe mode today, I don't know which mess I smoking today :-)

Answer (score 0):

Btw. you should set your NimbusLookAndFeel [this way:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/nimbus_laf.html)

```
for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
    }
}
```

for all not SUN JREs Java 1.7 which have a `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel` and no `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel`